# sizeForItemAtIndexPath is not found in different swift versions

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using UICollectionView but following method not found:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

please suggest me it's replacement.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is the new syntax for that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

}
```

Answer (score 82):

For me `sizeForItemAt` wasn't called because in Swift 3 you need to explicitly set your class to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol

Comment: You saved my lot time, as I am not very familiar with CollectionView but I have to use it for one of my apps.
+1 for your very important instruction

Comment: Especially useful, when you just migrated an existing project to Swift 3 and wondered why your collection views are suddenly broken.